# Codeigniter transferring data from one table to another using for loop

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to move data from one table to another in my model. In the first two lines I am getting all of the rows in my 'cart' table that match the username. I am now trying to iterate through all of these and match the product ID to the product ID in my 'product' table. I am then trying to format the data to fit my new table called 'sold'. However I am getting an error. I think the syntax of $q->id, $q->product_name etc is wrong. I know you can usually use that in the view but it does not work in the model. Do you know what the correct syntax would be to do this?

```
 function checkout($username){
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get('cart');
    //$data = array();

    foreach ($query as $q){
        $product = $this->db->get_where('product', array('id' => $q->id));
        $arr['product_id'] = $product->id;
        $arr['product_brand'] = $product->item_brand;
        $arr['product_name'] = $product->item_name;
        $arr['product_image'] = $product->item_image_url;
        $arr['product_price'] = $product->item_price;
        $arr['product_size'] = $product->item_size;
        $arr['name_of_seller'] = $product->name_of_lister;
        $arr['name_of_buyer'] = $this->session->userdata('username');

        $this->db->insert('sold', $arr);
    }
    //Deletes the items out of the cart
   // $this->db->delete('cart');
}
```

This is the error message I am getting

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, It would be much better to avoid using images in your questions when you want to show something very important like error message you got. images are not indexable by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `result()` to get the data in the the `$query` variable.

```
$query = $this->db->get('cart')->result();
```

In the same way, also change the second query.

```
$product = $this->db->get_where('product', array('id' => $q->id))->result();
```

See if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkout($username){
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$query = $this->db->get('cart');

if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
    $qdata = $query->result_array();

    foreach ($qdata as $key => $qdvalue) {
        $this->db->where('id', $qdvalue['id']);
        $product = $this->db->get('product');
        $pdata = $product->row_array()
        $inarray = array(
            'product_id'        =>      $pdata['id'],
            'product_brand'     =>      $pdata['item_brand'],
            'product_name'      =>      $pdata['item_name'],
            'product_image'     =>      $pdata['item_image_url'],
            'product_price'     =>      $pdata['item_price'],
            'product_size'      =>      $pdata['item_size'],
            'name_of_seller'    =>      $pdata['name_of_lister'],
            'name_of_buyer'     =>      $this->session->userdata('username')
        );

        $this->db->insert('sold', $inarray);
    }//end of foreach
}//end of if query
}//end of checkout function
```

I rewrite your function if all the column values right then It will work.
And I will suggest you to use transactions for this type of db events.